# SAS: How to loop though work file to append multiple database tables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a large list of database tables that I need to append into one amalgamated table on SAS.

- This table list changes regularly.
- Some tables in this list don't have don't use the same column names.
- Where the column name is different, the list will indicate what the equivalent name is.

This table list is imported into SAS from a csv file and resembles the below data:

| index | table_name | column_1_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | table_one_a | column1 |
| 2 | table_one_b | columnOne |
| 3 | table_one_c | column_1 |
| 4 | table_one_d | column_1_1 |
| etc ........ | etc..... | etc..... |

I want to append every table in this list, and then change the names where applicable by referencing the column_1_name column in the above list.

The below code was adapted from [this link](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Appending-dataset-in-Macro-loop/td-p/311607) and is an illustration of how I want SAS to append the tables together from the above list. However I don't know how to convert the above list of tables with their column names into variables so they can be looped through in the below illustrated macro.

Is there a way that I can convert this list of tables into a variable that I can then looped through by its index number?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
 libname dbname ODBC DSN=databaseName;

 %let table = table_one_a; run;

 %let column_one = column1; run;

 %MACRO append_tables;

     %If index =1 %Then %Do;

     data first_table;
     set dbname.&table.;
     &column1. = column1; 
     keep column1 column2  etc;
     run;

     %End;

     %Else %Do;

     data later_table;
     set dbname.&table.;
     &column1. = column1; 
     keep column1 column2  etc;
     run;

     proc append 
     BASE = first_table
     DATA = later_table;
     run;

     %End;

 %MEND;
```

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your actual requirements.

Comment: Hi @Reeza, I've added some modifications now to reflect that modifications to the naming conventions of some tables would be dependent on the table list.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think this explains your use case as described.

Comment: Why do you have a macro definition that it is referencing macro variables whose source is not defined?  If they are inputs to the macro then make them parameters of the macro in the %MACRO statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop, why don't you just extract all the tables name from the list? Also, why are you not using a single `SET` statement instead of the `APPEND` procedure?

```
*-- Create table list sample --*;

data csv_list;
length column_name $20.;
table_name = "table_one_a"; column_name = "Col1"; output;
table_name = "table_one_b"; column_name = "Column1"; output;
table_name = "table_one_c"; column_name = "Colonne1";output;
run;

*-- Create synthetic data for each table in table list --*

data temp.table_one_a;  
Col1 = 1;
run;

data temp.table_one_b;
Column1 = 2;
run;

data temp.table_one_c;
Colonne1 = 3;
run;
```

```
libname temp "/home/kermit/stackoverflow";

*-- Create macro tables with all table names + renaming --*

proc sql;
  select cats(strip("temp."||table_name),"(rename=(",column_name,"=column1))") into :tables separated by " "
    from csv_list;
quit;

*-- Append using set statement --*

data want;
  set &tables.;
run;
```

```
*-- Tables macro is a concatenation of all table names in table list, separated by a space --*

%put &=tables;
TABLES=temp.table_one_a(rename=(Col1=column1)) temp.table_one_b(rename=(Column1=column1)) 
 temp.table_one_c(rename=(Colonne1=column1))


*-- Result is the vertical combination of all tables + renaming in the tables macro --*

data _null_;
set want;
put id;
run;

column1
   1   <-- table_one_a
   2   <-- table_one_b
   3   <-- table_one_c
```

Comment: Hi @Kermit, I did originally think of using the SET function, though I was hoping to use a data step before any appends so that I can change the column names as a lot of the tables use different names for the same column. Which was why I was thinking of using a loop instead.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. It handles columns renaming.

Comment: Thanks @Kermit, it's quite late where I am so I'll test this tomorrow.

Comment: I believe OP wants to selectively rename some columns in some tables and the renaming is to standardize the names across various data sets.

Comment: Hey @Kermit, just tested it now and your solution worked for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Reeza which is exactly what my program does? I don't understand the point.